# pandas puts NaN for values whenever assigning to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I faced to a really weird problem in pandas.

I have fetched the google data using the following code:

```
start_date = '2014-01-01'
end_date = '2018-01-01'
google_data = data.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
```

I would try to have another dataframe called `google_data_signal` and create it without any problem:

```
google_data_signal = pd.DataFrame(google_data.index)
```

**Problem:**
Whenever I want to add `Adj Close` column to `google_data_signal` from `google_data`, it places NaN values, while they aren't.

```
google_data_signal['price'] = google_data['Adj Close']
```

**PS:** You can see the values of it using `print(google_data['Adj Close'].head())`.

Comment: Try `google_data_signal['price'] = google_data['Adj Close'].values`

Comment: @Aramakus why this problem has happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this problem occurring is the index mismatch. When you assign from an array using `.values`, the indexing of the dataframe on the left is used, because of avoiding (index mismatch) conflict.